# MySQL 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I'm stuck with this infamous error and can't figure out what went wrong. I'm trying to establish relationship between two tables `orders` and `payments`, whose migrations are defined as:

```
class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('partner_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('status', 20)->default(Order::getDefaultStatus());
            $table->string('paid', 20)->default('no');

            $table->decimal('visitation_charges', 20, 2)->default(0); 
            $table->decimal('taxes', 20, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('charges', 20, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('discount', 20, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('total', 20, 2)->default(0);

            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('partners')->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
}

class CreatePaymentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('gateway', 100);
            $table->string('transaction_id', 100);
            $table->decimal('amount', 20, 2);
            $table->string('status', 20)->default(Payment::getDefaultStatus());
            $table->string('comments', 2000)->nullable();

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('orders')->onDelete('set null')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('payments');
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `payments` add constraint `payments_order_id_foreign` foreign key (`order_id`) references `orders` (`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)
```

I've also verified that the table engines, column types, character set, etc., are the same (following are the outputs of `show create`):

```
| orders | CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `partner_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'created',
  `paid` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `visitation_charges` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `taxes` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `charges` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `discount` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `orders_customer_id_foreign` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `orders_partner_id_foreign` (`partner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `orders_partner_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

| payments | CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gateway` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  `comments` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. :/

Comment: Could there be any records in `payments` whose `order_id` refers to non existent records in the `orders` table?  This is the first thing I would check.

Comment: Is your order table created before payments? Or could there be any records in payments whose order_id doesn't exist in the order table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a foreign key `ON DELETE SET NULL` for columns declared as `NOT NULL`.

The column can't be NULL.

The foreign key works if you do either of the following:

- Omit the `ON DELETE SET NULL`:

  ```
  alter table `payments` add constraint `payments_order_id_foreign` 
  foreign key (`order_id`) references `orders` (`id`) on update cascade;
  ```
- Modify the column to allow NULL:

  ```
  alter table payments modify order_id int(10) unsigned null;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Add **nullable()** on order_id column. Like below. Your error will be gone.

```
class CreatePaymentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // your others columns
         $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should better you build another migration for foreign key:

`php artisan make:migration add_foreign_key_to_payment_table --table=payments`

so add payments foreign key to this migration, then run `php artisan migrate`

if the error still exists you must drop manually orders and payments table and remove them from migration table then add those again.

I hope this will help you. Good day! :)